# Why doesn't tableview delegate work?

Tags: uitableview, swift

I have the following class in a singleview app.  In IB, I have connected the datasource and datadelegate to the tableview.  Is there something I'm doing wrong that none of the tableview delegates fire?

The cell identifier is set in IB.

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UITableViewController {

    let myarray = ["item 1", "item 2", "item 3", "item 4"]
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier: "test")
        cell.textLabel?.text = myarray[indexPath.item]
        return cell;
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 4
    }

}
```

There is already a prototype cell in IB.

One other thing, viewDidLoad() doesn't even fire.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are supposed to dequeue cells in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`.  In storyboard, add a UITableViewCell to the table if there isn't one already, and you should see a prototype cell.  Make sure that the identifier of the prototype is "test" like it is in your code.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    var cell:UITableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("test") as UITableViewCell

    cell.textLabel?.text = self.myarray[indexPath.row]

    return cell
}
```

Comment: Okay, check the identifier of the prototype cell, and also change the method as I described above.

Comment: As mentioned in the OP, the identifier is there.  What should the method change to?

Comment: The identifier won't be there when you change the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` to what I have above.  Do you not see the code in my answer? :)  You're allocating a new cell every with that identifier every time the table is reloaded.  Instead, you need to dequeue a cell if one is available with that identifier.  Instead of creating the cell in the method, you need to add it to the storyboard.  You do not mention having the prototype cell in the storyboard in your original post.

Comment: I see.  I've changed it to dequeue a cell.  Still no activity though.  I've updated the OP to include a comment about the prototype cell.

Comment: are you calling `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` like I have in my code?  You didn't update your code to reflect.

Comment: Yes - I mentioned that in the previous comment.  I can't keep updating my OP with changes toward the right answer since the OP wouldn't make sense anymore.  That's the reason your providing the answer. Otherwise, the OP would just be an answer and not make any sense.

Comment: I've updated the OP with a comment that viewDidLoad() doesn't even fire in this class.  Besides the initial NavController, this view is the only one in the project.

Comment: Click on the view controller in storyboard and go to its identity inspector.  Is the class ViewController or UITableViewController?  Also, ensure that the  initial view controller checkbox is checked.  There should be a gray arrow in storyboard pointing to this view controller.

Comment: Ah - the class was UITableViewController.  I changed it to ViewController and now everything works.